# How to pass command line arguments to a bash script called using Exec function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, bash, git

I have written a bash script that stores the total number of lines and path of all  the files that are fetched from the local git repo in my machine to an excel sheet. I call this bash script from the excel macro (VBA) using the Exec function. The script takes arguments such as git-repo-url, branch-name and the path where it has to be cloned if not present in the machine.

Bash script i have written is as follows:

```
if [ ! -d "$3" ]
then
    git clone "$1" "$3"
fi
cd "$3"
git checkout "remotes/origin/$2"
git pull origin $2
git ls-files  | grep '\.java$\|\.cpp$' | xargs wc -l | awk ' BEGIN {printf( 
"%5s\n", "Count \t Path")} { printf ("%6s\n", $1 "\t" $2 )}' > new.xls
```

Below is the Vba code i tried to call the bash script with the arguments:

```
reponame = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Snap shot").Range("J3")
branchname = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Snap shot").Range("J4")
dirname = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Snap shot").Range("J5")

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe 
C:/demo/script.sh reponame branchname dirname").StdOut.ReadAll
```

Here reponame, branchname and dirname are inputs from the user and has the corresponding values in it.
Bash Scripts executes as expected when i hard code the values as command line arguments instead of variable names. When i pass the variables as arguments, it takes the variable names and not the value of the variables.

How to pass the variable as the arguments using Exec function in Vba?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) please [edit] your question and add the code as text formated as code block. Checkout the [help] for how to do that. • Also you need to tell what is going wrong with your code, where you got errors and which. Finally you need to ask a question as you didn't ask one yet (see [ask]).

Comment: CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe C:/demo/script.sh " & reponame & " " & branchname & " " & dirname).StdOut.ReadAll

Comment: Thanks MacroMarc  fro your reply. It is working...

Comment: Sure - you have to make VBA evaluate each of the string variables and concatenate into one long string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the variables into the string using the `&` sign:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe C:/demo/script.sh " & reponame & " " & branchname & " " & dirname).StdOut.ReadAll
```